# Why can't Eclipse Jetty Plugin see org.json.simple.parser.ParseException?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jetty, embedded-jetty, jetty-9

I am using Eclipse
Version: 2019-06 (4.12.0)
Build id: 20190614-1200
with Eclipse Jetty Feature 4.0.0

When I run my web server via the maven-jetty-plugin, it seems to work, but when I run the same project under the Eclipse Jetty, I get

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /weather. Reason:

    Server Error

Caused by:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/simple/parser/ParseException
. . .
```

In my POM I have

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
  <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

which is required to compile, and it shows up in my project's Maven Dependencies in Eclipse, and I can see the ParseException class there. In the Jetty Run Configurations I can see the Maven Dependencies in the Dependencies tab and the Classpath tab. But for some reason, when Jetty runs and calls my servlet, it blows up.

Interestingly, when running from Maven, my calls to

```
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(json);
String description = (String) jsonObject.get("description");
```

`description` is null, and `parse` and `get` do not throw any exceptions.

At this point I am quite baffled, and would appreciate any tips or ideas.

Comment: Can you show the Jetty run configuration?

Comment: Do you mean the Eclipse Jetty Run Configuration? Is there some easy way to show it, aside from going through the GUI exhuastively?

Comment: If this is in a Dynamic Web Project and you're using Jetty from the Servers View, you'll need to mark the json jar in the project's Deployment Assembly property page.

Comment: Server classes cannot be seen by WebApp classes and vice-versa, they are isolated.   Put that jar in to your WebApp properly, so that it shows up in the WEB-INF/classes location.